# Get detailed StackTrace information using C#

Tags: c#, exception

I'm catching every exception in my project and logging it using log4net.

I would like to get a detailed information of this exception and a detailed trace of this (with arguments (and its value), source line, and so on).

How could I get this information?
Does exist any nuget package provide me with that?

Comment: Is the `StackTrace` class enough for you? What are you missing? (Make sure to include the PDB files on deployment)

Comment: There's a complete example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exception` class has a `TargetSite` property, which gives you the method that threw that exception. You can also unfold the stack frame to dive deeper for example

```
var method = e.TargetSite.Name;
var parameters = e.TargetSite.GetParameters();
var stackTrace = new StackTrace(e);
var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
```

[image]

Comment: @Jordi havent found one yet, how ever you use any of the Application Monitoring tools like New Relic, App Dynamics etc. I dont know if you can use interception for this, have a look at Code Cop